# How to do ls with a wildcard and see the directory name

Tags: directory, ls

I have a directory called selenium_IDE

if I do

```
ls sel*
```

I get to see directories that are in it, e.g.

```
$ ls sel*
HAPPY              HAPPY_PLUS_OPTIONS SAD                SAD_PLUS_OPTIONS
```

but not the directory itself, i.e. `selenium_IDE/`

I tried using `-d1` (depth 1) which has worked for me in the past on some system.  It does work in that it shows the selenium_IDE directory but also shows a error  here on OSX

```
$ ls sel* -d1
ls: -d1: No such file or directory
selenium_IDE:
HAPPY              HAPPY_PLUS_OPTIONS SAD                SAD_PLUS_OPTIONS
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Accepting command options arguments after file operands is not standard and isn't often supported in non-GNU system, you need:

```
ls -d1 sel*
```

---

A note that `-d1` isn't *depth 1* like you think.

- `-d` tell `ls` list directories themselves, not their content
- `-1` tell `ls` list one entry per line

Comment: You are the coolest kid on the block!